# How do I get the sum of a txt file and a binary file both of which have array size of 10?

Tags: c, file

My code is very likely to be incorrect everywhere since I just go started on learning files.
The array of the text file is {3 2 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 3}
The array of the binary is {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZ 10
int main()
{
    int arr_in[ARR_SIZ];
    int arr_bin[ARR_SIZ];
    int i = 0;
    FILE * fp_in = fopen("data/in.txt", "r");
    FILE * fp_bin = fopen("data/in.bin", "wb");
    fread(arr_in, sizeof(int), ARR_SIZ, fp_in);
    fread(arr_bin, sizeof(int), ARR_SIZ, fp_bin);
    int sum[ARR_SIZ];
    for (i=0; i < ARR_SIZ; i++){
            fscanf("%d", arr_in);
    fscanf("%d", arr_in);
    sum[i] = arr_in[i] + arr_bin[i];
    } printf("%d", sum[i]);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are gonna need bigger buffer if you wish to read the whole line. How does the text file look line? one line `{3 2 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 3}` ?

Comment: `fscanf("%d", arr_in);` will not compile, and anyway it would overwrite the data you already `fread`.

Comment: @TonyTannous yes

Answer (score 0):

`fread()` reads binary data even when the file is not opened with `"b"` which just means it doesn't do funny stuff with things like Windows-style line breaks.
If you want to read a text file you will how to do more complex work like reading in the data, look for line breaks, and than use the data before each line break. As that data is still a string you will need to convert it to an integer (e.g. using `atoi()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple program (without `fread()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void) {
    FILE *text = fopen("in.txt", "r"); // --- declaration
    FILE *binr = fopen("in.bin", "r");
    int text_number[SIZE], binary_number[SIZE], sum = 0;
    // alt: you can change sum to sum[SIZE] = {0} if you want to hold into an array.

    // --- reading data and assigning into arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        fscanf(text, "%d", &text_number[i]);
        fscanf(binr, "%d", &binary_number[i]);
    }

    // --- summation
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        sum += text_number[i] + binary_number[i]; // alt: do sum[i] when you do sum[SIZE]
        printf("%d ", sum); // alt: do sum[i]
        sum = 0; // should be omitted when you change into sum[SIZE]
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**in.bin** contains: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Similarly, **in.txt** contains: `3 2 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 3`

And the result is: `4 4 4 7 9 11 13 9 11 13` (sum of both files' integers taken by array).

**Note:** If you want to store the `sum` into array, then use the `alt` code.

I'm not very much aware of `fread()`, so I just did what I could at the moment.

Comment: Oh, the result should be 4 4 4 7 9 11 13 9 11 13. It should be the sum of each array with the same index

Comment: @mild code updated. Now see if it works, you can change the 'sum' to 'sum[SIZE]' and assign its value in each iteration of the last loop of the program.

Comment: @mild did that work? I had re-edited my code for the changes wherever you'll require to update if you use sum[SIZE].

Comment: @mild What do you mean by *outputs 6356600*? That should output: `4 4 4 7 9 11 13 9 11 13`.